# immutable getIn returns null but not notSetValue

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I have a simple state Record:

```
interface StateParams {
  priceObj: PriceDTO;
}

const defaultState = {
  priceObj: undefined,
}

class State extends Record(defaultState) implements StateParams {
  priceObj: PriceDTO;
}
```

By default it has undefined value.

Whatever comes, as a result of offerRequest is saved to `priceObj` and not transformed to immutable

```
(state: State, priceObj: PriceDTO) => state.set('priceObj', priceObj),
```

I have also simple selector:

```
export const getQuoteId = (state: State): string | undefined =>
  state.getIn(['offerData', 'priceObj'], {}).offerID;
```

Unfortunately it throws an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offerID' of null`

Is there any particular reason, why `getIn` does not return `notSetValue` value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state contains the key `priceObj` as you added it via the set operation in your reducer. `notSetValue` is only returned when the map doesn't contain the key. An explicit `null` is a valid value (as is `undefined`), hence why `{}` is not being returned.

You should either check `priceObj != null` before setting in state or make your selector something like:

```
export const getQuoteId = (state: State): string | undefined =>  
  (state.getIn(['offerData', 'priceObj']) || {}).offerID;
```